# Formal definition of an XML document

Tags: xml

Can someone provide a formal definition (not the specification, as it is too verbose) for an XML document? I searched online already, but could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search revealed the following syntax definitions:

- An [XML-1.0 EBNF](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/EBNF1.0.aspx)
- An [XML-1.1 EBNF](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/EBNF1.1.aspx)

Each of those links should suffice to create a parser.